# Correctly represent utf-8 string in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, utf-8, android-volley

I get a string representing a file url after making a Volley StringRequest in Android. The response is:

`"https:\/\/myserver.com\/relative\/file\/path\/\u0391\u0394...\u0395.pdf"`

After removing the extra back slashes, the string reads as:

"https://myserver.com/relative/file/path/\u0391\u0394...\u0395.pdf"

The utf-8 characters represent Greek letters.

I have made several attempts to read the characters correctly but to no avail. I have tried things like:

`mystring.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)`

and:

`mystring.byteInputStream(Charsets.UTF_8).bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).readText()`

Both of the above produce the same string with the characters unencoded. In contrast, the line: `"\u0391\u0394".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)` properly interprets the characters as "ΑΔ".

The content type on the response header is: `application/json; charset=UTF-8` which should be correct.

What should I do to properly interpret the characters in that string?

Comment: It could be a problem with the client double-escaping something. The literal way to express those Strings you are seeing is e.g. `"path\\/\\u0391\\u0394"`.